# SwiftUI and Firebase - Stream error: 'Not found: No document to update:

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

So, I have a program that, when it opens, looks for a specific document name in a specific collection (both specified) and, when it is found, copies the document name and starts a listener. If it doesn't find the document name after 5 x 5 second intervals, the app stops. For some reason, when I run the code, after it does the first check I get about a thousand writes of this error:

[Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] WriteStream (7ffcbec0eac8) Stream error: 'Not found: No document to update:

Here's the code I'm using to call firestore:

```
let capturedCode: String? = "party"

.onAppear(perform: {
            
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) { timer in
                print("running code check sequence")
                if let code = capturedCode {
                    calcCloud.checkSessionCode(code)
                    
                    if env.doesCodeExist {
                        print("code found! applying to environment!")
                        env.currentSessionCode = code
                        calcCloud.watchCloudDataAndUpdate()
                        allClear(env: env)
                        timer.invalidate()
                    }
                    else if timerCycles < 5 {
                        
                        timerCycles += 1
                        print("code not found, this is cycle \(timerCycles) of 5")
                        
                    } else {
                      print("could not find document on firebase, now committing suicide")
                        let x = ""
                        let _ = Int(x)!
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

here is the code I'm using to check firebase:

```
    func checkSessionCode(_ code: String) {
            print("checkSessionCode running")
                
                let docRef = self.env.db.collection(K.sessions).document(code)
                docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if document!.exists {
                        print("Document data: \(document!.data())")
                        self.env.doesCodeExist = true
                    } else {
                        print("Document does not exist")
                        self.env.doesCodeExist = false
    
                    }
                }
            }
```

and here is the code that should be executed if the code is found and applied:

```
func watchCloudDataAndUpdate() {
        
        env.db.collection(K.sessions).document(env.currentSessionCode!).addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
            guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching snapshot: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            guard let data = document.data() else {
                print("Document data was empty.")
                return
            }
```

Where did I go wrong, and what is this error all about...thanks in advance :)

EDIT: For clarity, it seems that the errors begin once the onAppear finishes executing...

Comment: Which line of code here generates that message?

Comment: it happens on the last closing brace of the .onAppear statement...I put preakpoints on every line of onAppear, seems like once onAppear runs it starts throwing the errors into the console

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to make that clear within the code itself?

Answer (score 2):

This is why I need to stop coding after 1am...on my simulator, I deleted my app and relaunched and everything started working again...sometimes the simplest answers are the right ones...

Comment: I had the same issue xd. I put Firebase Firestone code into a function that is called multiple times every second. I think the tasks stacked somewhere and after some minutes everything is fine again :)